# If-else inside a while statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, indexing, while-loop

Learning to code with Python 3. I am confused why my `else` statement keeps executing with the code below:

```
def countSubStringMatch(target, key):
    index = 0
    instance_list = []

    while index <= len(target):
        match = target.find(key,index)
        if match > -1:
            instance_list.append(match)
            index += 1
        elif match == -1:
            return None

    return sorted(set((instance_list)))

target1 = 'mjzzmjzzmjzz'
key1 = 'zz'

print(countSubStringMatch(target1, key1))
```

The point of this code is to list the indexes at which the key starts. I had the code running fine when there are actual instances of the key within target, but I am trying to edit it to return `None` when there are no instances. This was my code before the edit:

```
def countSubStringMatch(target, key):
    index = 0
    instance_list = []

    while index <= len(target):
        match = target.find(key,index)
        if match > -1:
            instance_list.append(match)
        index += 1

    return sorted(set((instance_list)))

target1 = 'mjzzmjzzmjzz'
key1 = 'zz'

print(countSubStringMatch(target1, key1))
```

Comment: You don't have an `else` clause.

Comment: I get the same result with an else clause.

Comment: If just enter a 'break' line everything work fine. But I explicitly want to return None.

Comment: @MJ49: **when** should `None` be returned?

Comment: Alternatively, `[i for i, l in enumerate(target1) if target1[i:i+len(key1)] == key1] if key1 in target1 else None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll *eventually always get `-1`*, as you inclement index. So yes, your `elif` is going to match and you end up returning `None`:

```
>>> target1 = 'mjzzmjzzmjzz'
>>> key1 = 'zz'
>>> target1.find(key1, 0)
2
>>> target1.find(key1, 3)
6
>>> target1.find(key1, 7)
10
>>> target1.find(key1, 11)
-1
```

So when `index = 11`, `target.find()` returns `-1` for your sample input. Since `len(target)` is 12, that is still within your loop.

Only return `None` when `instance_list` is empty. Also, increment your index to step *past* the last-found index, there is no point in incrementing the index by 1 each time; that way you avoid all the duplicate indices and removes the need to use a set:

```
def countSubStringMatch(target, key):
    index = 0
    instance_list = []

    while index <= len(target) - len(key):
        match = target.find(key, index)
        if match == -1:
            break
        instance_list.append(match)
        index = match + 1

    return instance_list or None
```

There is no point in searching from an index equal to the length of the target minus the length of the key; you are not going to find the key at index 11.

This returns `None` if no matches were found, rather than a list. You may want to reconsider this; testing for an empty list is just as easy and makes your API consistent (always returning a list, which may be empty):

```
>>> target1 = 'mjzzmjzzmjzz'
>>> key1 = 'zz'
>>> countSubStringMatch(target1, key1)
[2, 6, 10]
>>> countSubStringMatch(target1, 'foo') is None
True
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant to say there; I can comment on deleted posts.

Comment: Good way to elicit participation is by asking questions, if you guillotine everyone that attempts to participate, you will participate in making this a ghost town with you as the sheriff

Comment: Should I not comment when I vote on your answers from now on then? I give feedback whenever I do so, and always happy to retract when the issue has been resolved. As to your accusation I did this to you before, I cannot find any reference to us having competed on a question before, nor do I appear to have commented on any of your posts before. I searched for [previous still undeleted interactions](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/25355/have-we-met), all your deleted answers and my deleted comments.

Comment: Well I guess it is another aggressive diamond. It is good to want to maintain the quality and I certainly appreciate it. But as pavlov discovered, negative feedback elicits a negative response. I was working on my answer, (which looks quite the same with the exception of the break vs. return)

Comment: That's the issue though, the *return is the cause of confusion here*.

Comment: True, if not expected, I would have returned an empty list. But, since we don;t know where this will end up, the point is moot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86918/discussion-between-incognos-and-martijn-pieters).